# PHP MYSQL PDO - Delete rows on DB to match the value defined for number of rows on the code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Maybe is a dumb question but I am new to PHP and Mysql. I am building a login system for practice purposes, I am stuck and your guidance will be much appreciated.

On my DB I have 2 tables 1 for user login (users) and other for password history (pwdhistory) logs. Whenever a user is created or changes the password the code updates the users table with the new password and also insert into pwdhistory the user data and this is working fine.

I want to limit the maximum entries for a user to 3 on pwdhistory table and that I believe I can do it. The issue is, now that I am coding I have more than 3 entries on the pwdhistory table for a specific user (user_id) and when I run my code it deletes all the records from the user on the DB. What I really want is to delete the additional rows based on the oldest date to match 3 entries, that is what I am having hard time doing it. Your assistance would be much appreciated.

-- Table structure for table `pwdhistory`

```
CREATE TABLE `pwdhistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `changedate` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

-- Table structure for table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_pwd_reset` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

The below is my code for the above problem statement and the result is the delete of all the rows for the specific user_id.

PHP scripts for the delete
//check if passwords for a user is more than 3
`$checkUserPwdRecords = checkUserPwdRecords($id); //checkUserPwdRecords` is returning 4

```
if($checkUserPwdRecords > 3) {

            do{
                $deleteUserPwdRecords = deleteUserPwdRecords($id);
        
            } while($checkUserPwdRecords > 3);  
        }
```

Functions

```
function checkUserPwdRecords($id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = "SELECT password FROM pwdhistory WHERE user_id = ? ";
        
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);           
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
            return $result;     
    }

function deleteUserPwdRecords($id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = "DELETE FROM pwdhistory WHERE user_id = ? AND changedate IS NOT NULL order by changedate desc LIMIT 1 ";       
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
        $stmt->execute();       
    }
```

Comment: I think you should look into MYSQL triggers for this. You can save a lot of PHP code and have everything working with few lines of SQL

Comment: `I want to limit the maximum entries for a user to 3 on pwdhistory table`...why, what will that achieve? It's unclear what the practical purpose of bothering to implement this would be.

Comment: @ADyson as said I am practising and I believe it can be applied in case of a migration to this app, in case that the data on the old DB pwdhistory have more than 3 entries per user.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why limiting the history to 3 entries would be meaningful. What problem does implementing that requirement solve for you? It seems to be a completely arbitrary limitation.

Comment: That's a funny piece of code. it should actually fall into an endless loop because $checkUserPwdRecords doesn't seem to be changed and should be still > 3 no matter how many records were deleted

Answer (score -1):

This part of code is unclear as people on comment section saying, it should fall into a inf loop And even if it is working, maybe it is not a best practice as User might have many login logs and that would be a loop with O(n) iterations.

```
if($checkUserPwdRecords > 3) {

            do{
                $deleteUserPwdRecords = deleteUserPwdRecords($id);
        
            } while($checkUserPwdRecords > 3);  
        }
```

But anyway, I came up with an idea that we can actually make a query in which can hold three first (oldest) records, and delete the rest. Here is the SQL:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM table_name
  ORDER BY date ASC
  LIMIT 3
) AND // other conditions like user id;
```

Comment: Thank you I manage to get it working. Thanks @Davood Ghanbarpour